# GitHub Actions Trigger Publish Job Only When Releasing a Package

Tags: sbt, github-actions

I have a Scala based multi module project for which I'm having a GitHub Actions pipeline which contains two jobs, one for test and the other for publishing to GitHub packages. Here is my file:

```
name: Build my projects

on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'images/**'
      - README.md
    branches:
      - master
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

  release:
    types: [ created ]

env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Cache ivy2
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.ivy2/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sbt-ivy-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/*.sbt') }}-${{ hashFiles('project/build.properties') }}

      - name: SBT Test
        run: sbt clean test

  publish:
    needs: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: SBT Publish
        run: sbt publish
```

I would need the following:

1. Trigger the publish job only when I want to do a release, but how do I know that I want to do a release? Do I tag a release when I commit the changes? If I tag it, then how can I check if there is a tag so that I know that I have to run the publish job?

Comment: You also have "manual" jobs that you can trigger manually when you want to release.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Do you have a solution that you can answer?

Comment: Note that you can also extract shared steps in their own file (without triggers) and create one workflow per kind of trigger referencing shared steps from other files.

Comment: Yes, I could move the entire release job in its own file, but how do I make sure that the test job is run before the release in that case? Here I can add the needs desciption to tell that I need to run job x before I can run the current job.

Comment: In the release workflow you reference the test workflow. See for instance https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-scala/blob/main/.github/workflows/release-sbt.yml#L13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger a workflow "only when you want to do a release", one option is to manually launch the workflow.

This can be achieved with a specific workflow with following trigger `workflow_dispatch`:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      releaseVersion:
        description: 'Release version'
        required: true
```

Here I add an input value that has to be entered manually when launching the workflow. This is not mandatory though if you don't need any input.

See also: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/

---

*Note that triggering the workflow when a tag is pushed is also a solution that makes sense. It's really up to you.*

Comment: I would like to do exactly that. Trigger the publish job only when a tag is pushed. In my current set up, I do not have that possibility. I'm sure, I need to change some things in my yml file to acheive that. I'm not sure what!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this in the publish job:

```
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')
```

So when there is a tag, the publish job knows that it has to run and publish the new package.